# Abbreviations skipping a page in appendix

Tags: appendices, acronyms, glossary

so I am currently working on a university report for my semester exam, and have encountered a problem with the glossary/abbreviations part of the appendix. I want it to be so that the abbreviations start on the same page as the section title, but it ends up skipping a page, is there a way to fix this?

I have attached a photo of how it looks at the time of writing, as well as the code.

[image]

Below is the main:

```
\input{Preamble/Preamble.tex}
\input{Preamble/AAUSynopsis.tex}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\add@text{}
\newcommand\tagaddtext[1]{%
  \gdef\add@text{#1\gdef\add@text{}}}% 
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{%
  \maketag@@@{\llap{\add@text\quad}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\input{Bib/Glossary.tex}


\renewcommand{\glsclearpage}{}
\newglossarystyle{custom_acronyms}
{
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%  
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[1]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}
        & ##2
        \tabularnewline}%
}

\begin{document}
\input{Formalia/Forside.tex}
\input{Formalia/Titelblad.tex}
\input{Formalia/Underskrifter.tex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

%Text
\input{Text/01 - Introduction/Introduction.tex}
\input{Text/02 - Problem Analysis/2.0 - Problem Analysis Main.tex}
\input{Text/03 - Requirements/Requirements Main.tex}
\input{Text/04 - Design/Design Main.tex}
\input{Text/05 - Implementation/Implementation}
\input{Text/06 - Accept Test/TestMain}
\input{Text/07 - Discussion/DiscussionMain}
\input{Text/08 - Conclusion/ConclusionMain}

\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff

%Sektions indelt kildeliste (indsæt keywords i kildelisten)
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,keyword={general},title={Bibliography}] %USE 
\phantomsection
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,keyword={image},title={Images}]
\phantomsection
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,keyword={datasheet},title={Datasheet}]
\phantomsection

%\input{Text/09 - Appendix/Glossary}
\input{Text/09 - Appendix/Appendix.tex}


\end{document}
```

Below is the preamble:

```
%%%Layout%%%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,table,xcdraw]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{doi}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%requirements setup
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}



%Macros for SI units
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
  
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {ã}{{\~a}}1 {ẽ}{{\~e}}1 {ĩ}{{\~i}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1 {ũ}{{\~u}}1
  {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {Ẽ}{{\~E}}1 {Ĩ}{{\~I}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {Ũ}{{\~U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1 {¡}{{!`}}1 
}
\lstdefinestyle{MatLab}{ %Formatting for code in appendix
    language=Matlab,
    numbers=left,
    frame=L,
    stepnumber=1,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=1,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!40!black},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{C}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C
}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\small\nouppercase\leftmark}
\rhead{\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%%%Sprog og font%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{physics}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
%%%Grafik%%%
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{aaublue}{RGB}{33,26,82}% dark blue
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
  font=footnotesize,% set font size to footnotesize
  labelfont=bf % bold label (e.g., Figure 3.2) font
}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lscape}
%%%Matematik%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%%%Overskrifter%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{10pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}

%%%Kommentarer%%%
\usepackage{verbatim} 

%%%Kildehenvisninger%%%
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sortcites,natbib=true,sorting=none,date=iso,seconds=true]{biblatex}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\addbibresource{Bib/Kilder.bib}

%%%Appendix og indholdsfortegnelse%%%
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\appto\appendix{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}}


%Ændrer * til cdot notation
\mathcode`\*="8000
{\catcode`\*\active\gdef*{\cdot}}

%Pakke til SI enheder
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Pakke til glossary

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

%Pakke til .svg figurer
\usepackage{svg}

%Pakke til wrapfigure
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Enable hyperlinks and insert info into the pdf file
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    %pdfpagelabels=true,%
    plainpages=false,%
    pdfauthor={Author(s)},%
    pdftitle={Title},%
    pdfsubject={Subject},%
    bookmarksnumbered=true,%
    colorlinks=false,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,% you should probably change this to black before printing
    urlcolor=black,%
    pdfstartview=FitH%
}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Enables file trees, which can be generated using
%https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/latex-dirtree-generator
\usepackage{dirtree}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{aaublue}{RGB}{33,26,82}% dark blue
\definecolor{mGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mGray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mPurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backgroundColour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{CStyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,             
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C,
    tabsize=4,
    tabsize=2,
}
```

Below is the Appendix Main:

```
\chapter{Appendix}
\setcounter{section}{0}% Reset numbering for sections
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/Glossary}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/CAN_Bitfields.tex}
%\include{Text/09 - Appendix/Figures.tex}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/Source Code.tex}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/Compression Rate Test}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/Delete Files Test}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/OV7670_output_format_test}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/Prototype Design.tex}
```

And Here is the Glossary file:

```
\section{Abbreviation}\label{app:abbreviation}
\setglossarystyle{list}
\setlist[description]{style = standard}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={}]
```

Comment: Could you trim this down to the necessary material to reproduce (good chance listings and bibliography stuff aren't needed) and make it compilable (remove all the `\include`/`\input`s that don't point anywhere)